# Google Cloud Service API enable/disable: ERROR: (gcloud.services.enable) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied to enable service

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Right now when I try and enable any service

```
gcloud services enable bigquery.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable storage-component.googleapis.com
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.services.enable) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied to enable service [storage-component.googleapis.com]
Help Token: Ae-hA1P6ojw8tvTr10ry2uqY2kJXDrVEcLhqmX-6wb-AhM6XmcfVsnMLzyHYVxcBv7r7hKHA8GYdrrUrOC8lzGT3qeNnWHE7iyaJ-m4r8SnMBuhp
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - subject: '110002'
    type: googleapis.com
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: serviceusage.googleapis.com
  reason: AUTH_PERMISSION_DENIED
```

What role do I need to add to my account in order to be able to enable and disable apis?

Comment: If you are local, did you `gcloud auth login` + `gcloud config set project` ?

Comment: @razimbres yes I did. I think I was missing "service usage admin" - see my answer

Comment: I checked here, maybe you could add a custom role attached to the service account at IAM as `serviceusage.services.enable`. Probably is more restrictive.

Answer (score 2):

I added the role "Service Usage Admin" and that let me run those commands. I don't know if it was overkill or not though.